FactoryBot - Test without creating associated factories
I'm working on a feature that I need to test. To test the feature I need to create an instance of my Build model. Usually this should not be a problem. My problem here is that Build has relations to many other models, none of which have any factories. In order to create my proper factory therefore I found myself in a rabbit hole trying to create a million factories for a million unrelated models. Is there a way around this?
